# C# Library for ASCII File import/mapping

Tags: c#, .net, interface, ascii

this is maybe a dump question but I give it a try.

One of a common task is to import data from ascii files.
It's almost always the same beside the structure of the file.
Comma separated, line seperated, take 5 rows, take 12... whatever...
So it's always a different protocol/mapping but the same handling...

Is there a library for c# which helps to support this day-to-day scenario?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is awesome: [FileHelpers Library](http://www.filehelpers.com)

**Example:**

File:

```
1732,Juan Perez,435.00,11-05-2002 
554,Pedro Gomez,12342.30,06-02-2004 
112,Ramiro Politti,0.00,01-02-2000 
924,Pablo Ramirez,3321.30,24-11-2002
```

Create a class that maps your data.

```
[DelimitedRecord(",")]
public class Customer
{
    public int CustId;

    public string Name;

    public decimal Balance;

    [FieldConverter(ConverterKind.Date, "dd-MM-yyyy")]
    public DateTime AddedDate;

}
```

And then parse using:

```
FileHelperEngine engine = new FileHelperEngine(typeof(Customer));

// To Read Use:
Customer[] res = engine.ReadFile("FileIn.txt") as Customer[];

// To Write Use:
engine.WriteFile("FileOut.txt", res);
```

Enumerate:

```
foreach (Customer cust in res)
{
   Console.WriteLine("Customer Info:");
   Console.WriteLine(cust.Name + " - " +
                  cust.AddedDate.ToString("dd/MM/yy"));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You may want to take a look at the [FileHelpers library](http://filehelpers.sourceforge.net/).

Answer (score 1):

So the only thing those tasks have in common is reading a text file?

If **FileHelpers** is overkill for you (simple text data, etc.), standard .NET classes should be all you need ([String.Split Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split.aspx), [Regex Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.aspx), [StreamReader Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamreader.aspx)).

They provide reading delimited by characters (`String.Split`) or lines (`StreamReader`).

Comment: Not to mention the framework's standard TextFieldParser class.

Comment: @Hans Passant: Yep, but that's only for the non-VB-phobic programmers :-P (that's meant assembly-wise)